# Testing Mongo with Docker

Tags: python, mongodb, unit-testing, docker, docker-compose

given the following file for docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:
  sut:
    build: .
    command: /bin/bash  #nosetests
    depends_on:
     - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
```

I try to connect to a mongo server on the fly. I didn't get very far with this ambitious plan. I assume the server the Mongo server is running with the docker container (named sut), e.g. I could address directly from Python with

```
MongoClient(host="localhost", port=27017)
```

Unfortunately I face problems to fire the above docker-compose up, e.g.:

```
thomas@linuxclientlobnek01:~/github/pydata$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up
Starting pydata_mongo_1
Recreating pydata_sut_1
Attaching to pydata_mongo_1, pydata_sut_1
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=cdaf9f862a16
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.8
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian71
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.967+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.976+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:03.976+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=8G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:04.076+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:04.076+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:04.076+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:04.076+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:04.076+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:04.076+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:04.076+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:04.076+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:04.076+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
mongo_1  | 2016-07-18T10:17:04.077+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
pydata_sut_1 exited with code 0
```

Any comments are very appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port `27017` is not published to your host machine so you can not connect to it from localhost.

You can change `mongo` block to

`mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
       - 27017:27017`

Or connect from docker container via docker container name:

`MongoClient(host="mongo", port=27017)`

Comment: Isn't it weird that on https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/ the ports for the Redis server are not defined? The Python program seems to connec to port 6379

Comment: It is not weird. By default [redis image](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/5d3e1e5ff708d038527c719d52f3e87f1970d721/3.2/Dockerfile#L49) exposes port 6379 so you can connect to redis from another docker container

Comment: Is it possible to rename the host "mongo" via docker-compose?

Comment: @tschm, yes. You can specify whatever name of container in docker-compose.yml. F.e. `services: my_favorite_db: image: mongo`

Comment: I have trouble to run mongo on a different port. I though ports: - "27050:27017" will do the job to connect via MongoClient(host="mongo", port=27050) ... Any insight here? I have been very careful in building my images and containers from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the same issue some time ago, as well as few more, so I wrote a short article/guide about it: [MongoDB in Docker-compose - installation in few steps (2019)](https://yosh.ke.mu/mongo_in_docker)

Sorry for shameless ad of my own blog, but I hope it's gonna save someone's time...